# Restore MySQL views line

Tags: mysql, view, restore

I have a MYSQL view (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html), I selected one record with a SELECTION query, I backed up that line but after by mistake I deleted that row (now I will get no results when I execute the same SELECTION query).
I have the backup in the form INSERT INTO view (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...).
How can I restore the backup line? I tried to execute the backup statement but the following message is shown:

```
The target table view of the INSERT is not insertable-into
```

I also have the original records in the tables that generate the view.
Can I recreate the view line from those tables?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's the only way for MySQL of today.

Comment: @VMai - How can I? I tried to execute the backup statement but the following message is shown:
The target table view of the INSERT is not insertable-into